# What is y(x,t) = Acos(kx - wt)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves

Im very new to wave mechanics and I've come across the following wave equation.

I know this is asking too much,but I wanted to know what is the

1. significance of this equation?
2. what does it tell us / what does it mean?

Comment: These issues are explained in detail in Hecht's book "Optics".

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I do not have that book right now and was wondering if I can get a direct answer. But yes yes, thank you! I'll make sure to search that book.

Comment: Hi Carina, do you know what k and w, as you write them, represent?

Comment: http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/travelling_sine_wave.htm#sine provides a very complete explanation.

Comment: Hi @count_to_10, to be honest all i know is that K is the "wave number" and  w has something to do with time. I don't understand why K is 2pi/wavelength and W is 2pi * frequency. :|

Thank you for showing the link. I have already read that several times as well, but I found myself still struggling. :(

Comment: As a matter of nomenclature this is not a "wave equation", but is "the equation of a traveling wave". The former is a differential equation whose solutions are waves; the latter is a solution to a particular wave equation.

Comment: Give me a minute to see if I can find a reference. In the meantime think about k as the wavenumber  (the number of waves in a certain distance, in radians) and w is the angular frequency which is 2.pi.frequency. I am kinda hoping these terms mean something to you :)  have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency

Comment: Thank you @count_to_10 yes somehow that makes sense to me. probably i just want to know how and where did it come from. as it's all really confusing. @_@ Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Basically, you need k and w to be able to tell you the amplitude of the wave at a. A particular position x and b. A particular time t. That's why k is a distance e and w is basically a time.

Comment: Finally, have a look at YouTube and I will leave you to it. Best of luck. Its worth watching, i think https://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=GxAyRJjCAsQ

Answer (score 11):

It is an expression describing a travelling wave. More precisely, it should say
$$ y(x,t) = A \cos (kx - \omega t) $$
where $x$ is the coordinate in space (location along a line in the direction where the wave is moving), $t$ is time, $k$ is $2\pi / \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the wave length, and the Greek letter omega $\omega = 2\pi f$ is the angular frequency (frequency in hertzes multiplied by $2\pi \approx 6.28$.

[image]

The function "cos" is the cosine, a function that oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$. The graph of the function is above. It may be imagined e.g. as the height of a valve on a wheel of a car as a function of time – or the location of the end of the spring that oscillates. The oscillations that depend on time through the cosine are known as the harmonic oscillations.

The number $A$ is just a coefficient, the maximum amplitude, that dictates the strength of the oscillations. Because the cosine is between $-1$ and $+1$, $A\cos (\dots)$ is between $-A$ and $+A$.

The argument of the cosine isn't just $\omega t$ but $kx - \omega t$. If we choose some appropriate units, it is the difference between the position and time. It means that the quantity $y(x,t)$ depends on the position in space $x$ in the same way as it depends on time – so even at one moment, it looks like the cosine wave in space.

There is a difference there. If we increase $\omega t$ and $kx$ by the same constant $\alpha$, the terms $\alpha$ cancel in $kx-\omega t$, so the value of $y(x,t)$ is the same. It means that waiting for some time has the same effect as looking to the right: the wave is moving to the right. It is moving by the speed $c=\omega / k$ which can be extracted as the slope of the line given by the equation $kx-\omega t={\rm  constant}$.

The periodicity of the cosine is $2\pi$. So if the argument of the cosine is changed by $2\pi$ (radians), we get the same value of the cosine. It means that $y(x,t)$ is a periodic (repeating) function of time as well as the space. The periodicity in time is $\Delta t = 2\pi / \omega$ because $\omega \cdot \Delta t = 2\pi$ while the periodicity in the spatial coordinate $x$ is the so-called wavelength (the distance between two maxima, for example), $\Delta x = 2\pi / k$, for an analogous reason.